# How to pass different template variables to one button in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, template-variables

There are more than two template variables in my component, just like blow:

```
<div #div1>
    <div #part1 [hidden]="true">
    </div>
    <div #part2>
    </div>
</div>
<div #div2>
    <div #part3 [hidden]="true">
    </div>
    <div #part4>
    </div>
 </div>
<button (click)="showDiv(div1,div2)"></button>
```

I wanna click the button to show part1 and hide part2, same as part3 and part4,  but it's just one button, what I can do now is to replace the div1 and div2 with part1 and part2, then what about part3 and part4? Another button? But the real request is more than two divs, maybe a dozen, so, can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you share some of the JavaScript code you're using?

Comment: What the most important is how to get the reference of  the current div that I click?

Comment: You can pass a parameter (e.g. showDiv('1')) saying which set of divs you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component you can add something like this

`

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}
showDiv(){
this.renderer.setStyle(
    this.el.nativeElement,
    'display:None',
    'block'
  );
}
```

`

Comment: It's not "angular Style". Just use a variable and use *ngIf="variable"

Comment: Then how to get the reference of the current div that I click?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you could use `ngContainer` and `ngTemplate`.

Using `ngContainer` and `ngTemplate`:

HTML:

```
<div> <!-- Div 1 -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="isPartVisible(1); then part1; else part2"></ng-container> 
  <ng-template #part1><div>Part 1</div></ng-template>
  <ng-template #part2><div>Part 2</div></ng-template>
</div>
<!-- Other parts here. -->
```

JavaScript:

```
var partVisibilities = {};
partVisibilities["1"] = true;

public isPartVisible(part) {
    return partVisiblities[part] == true; 
    // If you haven't set the visibility setting for a part yet, then it will not show as undefined is falsy in JS.
}
```